# AltGr dead key keyboard layout not working with Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

I am using a specific keyboard layout with Windows 10 using AltGr dead keys: to get an `é` I have to press `AltGr` + `'` then `e`.

It is working fine with all the installed software... except with Outlook ("Office 365 ProPlus" version).

If I start writing a "New Mail", with a new window showing up, it will work fine. But if I reply to an existing mail, so the edit frame is embedded in the main window, the dead keys will not work anymore: pressing the usual sequence will show `''e` instead of `é` (Note that the single quotes will appear differently depending on the "smart quotes" option).

I tried to modify all the autocorrect/autoformat/editing related options, without any chance.

Comment: Does it work with other Office applications like Word or Excel?

Comment: It works fine with Word and Excel.

Comment: Is this Outlook 2013? I have the same problem with Outlook 2013 and I'm curious to see if it is fixed in later versions.

Comment: I've just confirmed this issue to still be the (frustrating) case in the latest Outlook on Windows 10 (Microsoft Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12029.20342) 64 bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem. I know this is not a perfect solution but you can use Ctrl+Alt instead of Alt Gr.